# Write a one column of each row as separate file in hdfs by using pyspark

Tags: python-2.7, pyspark

I have a use case where the program needs to read one column from csv file and  write column in a data frame as a separate file to hdfs. For example if I have 10 lines in data frame means 10 output files need to be generate

Comment: post the code what you have tried plz..

Comment: from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext

final_data = spark.read.format("csv").load("input file location")

df1=final_data.select("column name").withColumn("num", monotonically_increasing_id())

df1.coalesce(1).write.partitionBy("num").text("location")

Comment: Here I have XML connect in one column. Final outputs need to generate like .XML files for all rows